# Jest - Pass the module path through a variable to Jest.mock()

Tags: module, jestjs, path, mocking

This is properly mocking the module:

```
jest.mock('./../../components/Spinner')
```

But this is not working:

```
  const path = './../../components/Spinner'
  jest.mock(path)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.